# How to add mock data containing authorized owner to Amplify (either through GraphiQL or directly to AppSync)?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, authorization, aws-amplify

I'm working on a React app and testing some CRUD functionality by mocking the backend, creating some data through GraphiQL, and running the app (`amplify mock`, then `yarn start`).

I want to be able to create mock data tied to my user as the owner because most types in the schema are set up with owner authorization:

```
type XYZ
   @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner, operations: [update, delete, create] }]) {
      id: ID!
      ...more types...etc
}
```

Right now, I

1. run `amplify mock`
2. Go to GraphiQL local endpoint (192.etc....)
3. Run some createXYZ mutations to create data
4. Run my app w `yarn start`
5. login with testUser & password
6. Test the `deleteXYZ` button which should ideally remove a particular XYZ from the mocked data **this is what doesn't work**

I suspect what's happening is that I didn't run the `createXYZ` mutation as testUser, just as a generic GraphiQL user, so the `owner` property isn't tied to "`myUserId`". Is that the problem here?

**How would I specify owner on my create mutations in GraphiQL?**

This is the error I'm getting, pretty sure it means the XYZ object's `owner` is different than my testUser submitting the deleteXYZ request:

```
Error while executing Local DynamoDB
{
    "version": "2018-05-29",
    "operation": "DeleteItem",
    "key": {
        "id": {
            "S": "18b152a6-c98d-4336-be74-1e122191"
        }
    },
    "condition": {
        "expression": "( #owner0 = :identity0) AND attribute_exists(#id)",
        "expressionNames": {
            "#owner0": "owner",
            "#id": "id"
        },
        "expressionValues": {
            ":identity0": {
                "S": "fd2a7758-f7ba-4d57-bdb0-e5346492"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Could I have to add the owner id in Amplify's GraphiQL Auth options popup?
[image: screenshot of user]

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue. I was able to work around it by putting my Cognito User Sub in the username field.

[image]